# Azure pipline: error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'D:\a\8\s\xxxPackager\obj\project.assets.json' not found

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines, msix

I have a Azure pipeline with a MSIX Build and Package step for a WPF solution that started occasionally failing last week (with no changes to the pipeline definition) and is now failing every time with the error:

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'D:\a\8\s\xxxxxx.Packager\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [D:\a\8\s\xxxxxx.Packager\xxxxxx.Packager.wapproj]`

The project in question is the UWP packaging project and has no nuget references and I've had many runs of the pipeline which were successful.

The difference I can see in the logs is the failed builds (before the error above) seem to be missing a line:

`Using shared compilation with compiler from directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn`

I seem some other questions and answers around the error above but none specifically pointing to the issue above. The wapproj is included in the solution. Carrying out a nuget restore for the .wapproj does not fix the issue.

It's very odd that it was working and suddenly isn't with no changes to the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make sure that you have add nuget restore task under pipeline. The restore should generate the guidance file `project.assets.json` file under `obj` folder. And that is necessary for build process.

[image]

**And**, you should moidfy your `xxx.wapproj` under azure repos and change `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools` nuget package to version `10.0.18362.3-preview`. From [this document](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools/), the other versions are abandoned.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.18362.3-preview" PrivateAssets="all" />
```